# Нахождение самого младшего и самого старшего человека из txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть txt файл в котором 5 строк(личный код человек,имя, фамилия)

1. 50001170299 Nikita Kuznecov
2. 50102184262 Mihail Smirnov
3. 50203198956 Edgar Fedorov
4. 50304205654 Semjon Volkov
5. 50405214987 Vadim Alekseev

---

где 1ая цифра у всех одинаковая

2ая и 3я цифры это 2 последние цифры года рождения

4ая и 5я цифры это номер месяца рождения(январь-01 и т.д)

6ая и 7ая цифры дата рождения(от 1 до 31)

остальные цифры произвольные.
и Нужно через python считать файл и вывести имя+фамилию самого младшего и самого старшего человека

```
code=open("new 1.txt", "r",-1,"utf-8")
info=code.readlines()
code.close()
for q in info:
#здесь как-то нужно произвести сравнение на самого младшего 
for w in info:
#здесь для самого старшего
print("Самый младший",q)
print("Самый старший", w)
```

Comment: Вы уже попробовали? Что получилось, что не получилось?

Comment: code=open("new 1.txt", "r",-1,"utf-8")
info=code.readlines()
print(info)
code.close()     это начало, дальше нужно это как-то записать в массив и сравнить друг с другом, но сравнивать ведь нужно не целые строки, а первые 7 цифр только нужны. И выводить только имя, фамилию

Comment: @Jevgewa, код добавляйте прямо в вопрос, не в комментарий. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос - нажмите "править" под ним.

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: домашнее задание?

Comment: да, на уроке дали задание, нужно дома доделать

Comment: Вы ничего не сделали и хотите, чтобы тут сделали ща вас? Тут так не делают.

Comment: у меня есть некоторые варианты, но частично, щас исправлю код в теме.

Comment: поправил немного

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open('info.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')

peoples = []
nums = []

for row in file.readlines():
   n = int(row.split()[0])
   peoples.append(' '.join(row.split()[1:]))
   nums.append(n)

max_years = nums.index(max(nums))
min_years = nums.index(min(nums))

print('Max: %s' % peoples[max_years])
print('Min: %s' % peoples[min_years])

file.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zeka\Desktop\python\dz.py", line 7, in <module>
    n = int(row.split()[0][:8])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: такая ошибка при компиляции

Comment: Я убрал номера строк в текстовом файле. Попробуйте изменить "[0][:8]" на "[1][:8]", а также строчкой ниже изменить " [1:]" на "[2:]".

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zeka\Desktop\python\dz.py", line 7, in <module>
    n = int(row.split()[1][:8])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Nikita'

Comment: теперь такое сообщение выдаёт

Comment: Вот полный текст моего info.txt:        50001170299 Nikita Kuznecov
50102184262 Mihail Smirnov
50203198956 Edgar Fedorov
50304205654 Semjon Volkov
50405214987 Vadim Alekseev

Comment: а, у вас в txt просто запись в строчку, у меня была каждый новый человек в отдельной строке.Я сделал щас как у вас в строку и  ошибок не возникло, НО он выводит просто всех людей почему-то

Comment: Max: Nikita Kuznecov 50102184262 Mihail Smirnov 50203198956 Edgar Fedorov 50304205654 Semjon Volkov 50405214987 Vadim Alekseev
Min: Nikita Kuznecov 50102184262 Mihail Smirnov 50203198956 Edgar Fedorov 50304205654 Semjon Volkov 50405214987 Vadim Alekseev

Comment: вот что он выводит, но такого же не может быть

Comment: у них же у всех разный год рождения

Comment: всё, разобрался. У меня просто были пустые строки

Comment: У меня каждый человек в новой строке. Можете изменить строку "n = int(row.split()[0][:8])" на "n = row.split()", а затем ниже добавить "print(n)" и скинуть вывод?

Comment: можно немного комментариев по коду ? вначле 2 массива объявляется это понятно, а дальше ..?

Comment: Структура личного кода позволяет использовать лексикографическое сравнение/сортировку, поэтому парсинг даты рождения излишен - можно просто использовать весь личный код целиком. ;)

Comment: предлагаете иное решение ?

Comment: @MaxU, Вы правы! Пропустил этот момент :о